# how to boot windows image backup?

Tags: windows, boot, backup, bootloader

The Windows boot loader is able to boot Windows from a full Image backup. I read that years ago, and about one year ago I even testet that myself, so I know it's true.

Now that I really need to boot a backup, I cannot find the Website any more and I have no clue what I did?

What I have is a full System Image of a Windows 8.1 installations (including boot Partition, Windows Partition and data/Profile Partition), but I cannot boot it. I don't have a free hard drive to restore it just for the few seconds I Need to extract some important pieces of data.

Mounting that Images is NOT enough, I Need the bootet System...

Comment: [First boot from a system repair disc](https://www.winhelp.us/restore-a-system-image-in-windows-7.html)

Comment: I know how to restore... But I want to boot the backup image directly. And I know that works...

Comment: You can't boot an Image Backup, as it contains no boot loader.  You may be able to force a boot-loader into it, but then it would (most likely) cease to be a valid backup image.

Comment: Assuming you backed up to a USB or network disc, even if you got the back-up OS into memory, it would expect to access disc files through ATA drivers, not USB or network drivers. The only way you might be able to boot is to remove the drive from its enclosure and plug it into the motherboard, but you are likely to need to go through a repair process first. This would of course compromise the disc as a back-up. If the main OS partition is small you could convert it to a VM and boot that, but there would be licensing issues.

Comment: I already copied the backup to the local hard drive. The method I am trying to use again uses the boot loader of the existing is with an additional boot entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot about this question...

The answer is here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-vhd--native-boot--add-a-virtual-hard-disk-to-the-boot-menu

See Step 4: Add a boot entry.